# need multiple outputs from single query - mysql

Tags: mysql

I want following output in mysql using single query from single table.

```
Total  Pending   Critical   Completed
  120      45         45         30
```

right now I am doing using 4 queries for for different column
like

```
select count(*) total from Y; -- for first column
select count(*) as Pending from Y where status = 0--- for second column
select count(*) as critical from Y where type = 'Critical' -- for third column
```

What I want, I want this in single query 
something like

```
select count(*) as total,count(*) pending where XYZ,
```

I am not getting what to write in where because conditions are different for each output,
if we write

```
select count(*) as total,count(*) pending where status = 0
```

then it gives

```
total pending
  45      45
```

but I want

```
total pending
  120      45
```

Please help me,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use CASE WHEN THEN like this:

```
select SUM(CASE WHEN  status = 0 THEN 1 END) as 'Pending ',
       SUM(CASE WHEN   type = 'Critical' THEN 1 END) as 'critical',
       COUNT(*) as 'Total'
from Y
```

Comment: Thank you So Much...! It is working as required and I think it is the best way, Thank you so much again..

Answer (score 0):

Best way I can see for you to do it is a query like

```
SELECT ( select count() total from Y) as total ,  
    ( select count() total from Y WHERE status = 0) as pending
```

Comment: ok but MySQL will execute these queries individually which is same as writing individual queries, Can we get in some more efficient way??